# Instagram API - paging through 'new' posts

Tags: javascript, api, node.js, instagram

So I'm using node.js and the module instagram-node-lib to download metadata for Instagram posts. I have a couple of hashtags that I want to search for, and I want to download all existing posts (handling request failure during pagination) as well as monitor all new posts.

I have managed to crack the first part - downloading all existing posts and handling failure (I noticed that sometimes the Instagram API would just fail on me, so I've added redundancy to remember the last successful page I downloaded and attempt again from that point). For anyone who is interested, here is my code (note, I use Postgres to save the posts, and I've abbreviated/obfuscated some of the code for ease of reading and for commercial purposes) **apologies for the length of code, but I think this will come in useful to someone:

```
var db = new (require('./postgres'))
    ,api = require("instagram-node-lib")
;

var HASHTAGS = ["fluffy", "kittens"] //this is just an example!
    ,CLIENT_ID = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
    ,CLIENT_SECRET = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"
    ,HOST = "https://api.instagram.com"
    ,PORT = 443
    ,PATH = "/v1/media/popular?client_id=" + CLIENT_ID
;

var hashtagIndex = 0
    ,settings
;

/**
 * Initialise the module for use
 */
exports.initialise = function(){
    api.set("client_id", CLIENT_ID);
    api.set("client_secret", CLIENT_SECRET);

    if( !settings){
        settings = {
            hashtags: [] 
        }

        for( var i in HASHTAGS){
            settings.hashtags[i] = {
                name: HASHTAGS[i],
                maxTagId: null,
                minTagId: null,
                nextMaxTagId: null,
            }
        }
    }
    // console.log(settings);

    db.initialiseSettings(); //I haven't included the code for this - basically just loads settings from the database, overwriting the defaults above if they exist, otherwise it creates them using the above object. I store the settings as a JSON object in the DB and parse them on load

    execute();    
}

function execute(){
    var params = {
        name: HASHTAGS[hashtagIndex],
        complete: function(data, pagination){
            var hashtag = settings.hashtags[hashtagIndex];

            //from scratch
            if( !hashtag.maxTagId){
                console.log('Downloading old posts from scratch');

                getOldPosts();
            }
            //still loading old (previously failed)
            else if( hashtag.nextMaxTagId){
                console.log('Downloading old posts from last saved position');

                getOldPosts(hashtag.nextMaxTagId);
            }
            //new posts only
            else {
                console.log('Downloading new posts only');

                getNewPosts(hashtag.minTagId);
            }
        },
        error: function(msg, obj, caller){
            apiError(msg, obj, caller);
        }
    }

    api.tags.info(params);    
}

function getOldPosts(maxTagId){
    console.log();

    var params = {
        name: HASHTAGS[hashtagIndex],
        count: 100,
        max_tag_id: maxTagId || undefined,
        complete: function(data, pagination){
            console.log(pagination); 

            var hashtag = settings.hashtags[hashtagIndex];

            //reached the end
            if( pagination.next_max_tag_id == hashtag.maxTagId){
                console.log('Downloaded all posts for #' + HASHTAGS[hashtagIndex]);

                hashtag.nextMaxTagId = null; //reset nextMaxTagId - that way next time we execute the script we know to just look for new posts
                saveSettings(function(){
                    next();
                }); //Another function I haven't include - just saves the settings object, overwriting what is in the database. Once saved, executes the next() function
            }
            else {
                //from scratch
                if( !hashtag.maxTagId){
                    //these values will be saved once all posts in this batch have been saved. We set these only once, meaning that we have a baseline to compare to - enabling us to determine if we have reached the end of pagination
                    hashtag.maxTagId = pagination.next_max_tag_id;
                    hashtag.minTagId = pagination.min_tag_id;                    
                }

                //if there is a failure then we know where to start from - this is only saved to the database once the posts are successfully saved to database
                hashtag.nextMaxTagId = pagination.next_max_tag_id;   

                //again, another function not included. saves the posts to database, then updates the settings. Once they have completed we get the next page of data
                db.savePosts(data, function(){
                    saveSettings(function(){
                        getOldPosts(hashtag.nextMaxTagId);         
                    });
                });
            }                        
        },
        error: function(msg, obj, caller){
            apiError(msg, obj, caller);
            //keep calm and try again - this is our failure redundancy
            execute();    
        }
    }

    var posts = api.tags.recent(params);
}

/**
 * Still to be completed!
 */
function getNewPosts(minTagId){

}

function next(){
    if( hashtagIndex < HASHTAGS.length - 1){
        console.log("Moving onto the next hashtag...");

        hashtagIndex++;

        execute(); 
    }   
    else {
        console.log("All hashtags processed...");
    } 
}
```

Ok so here is my dilema about solving the next piece of the puzzle - downloading new posts (in other words, only those new posts that have come into existence since I last downloaded all the posts). Should I use [Instagram subscriptions](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/) or is there a way to implement paging similar to what I've already used? I'm worried that if I use the former solution then if there is a problem with my server and it goes down for a period of time then I will miss out on some posts. I' worried that if I use the latter solution then it might not be possible to page through the records, because is the Instagram API set up to enable forward paging rather than backward paging?

I've attempted to post questions in the Google Instagram API Developers Group a couple of times and none of my messages seem to be appearing in the forum so I thought I'd resort to trusty stackoverflow

Comment: What about using subscriptions, and if you don't update soon enough so you miss some, falling back to the approach used in getOldPosts to resume from a failure at the last-seen post?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'd prefer to use a manual paging option if possible. Do you know if it's possible to page through records from a particular id (so paging through records we don't yet have, that exist since the last date we checked), a bit like Twitter's since_id and max_id system? [Twitter: Working with timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the Instagram API and can't spend the time to research it. I'm guessing you would've found it by now if it was supported. Why not ask them to add it?

Comment: I tried contacting Instagram via their Google Group but for some reason every time I create a new thread in the discussion it never appears in the forum. I tried creating a subscription but all subscriptions do is tell you that something has been added - not what has been added. Therefore, in my case, it's not fit for purpose. I feel like this needs to be resolved by Instagram...